# Creación de tablas temporales en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy usando SQL Sever. Mi duda es ¿puedo crear una tabla temporal sin definir sus columnas? o ¿existe alguna forma dinámica de crear una tabla temporal a partir de un `SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM DBO.TBLDATACOPY`?

El objetivo es crear una tabla temporal para almacenar los datos que devuelve un `SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM DBO.TBLDATACOPY` que se ejecuta mediante un `EXECUTE sp_executesql`. No puedo realizar lo siguiente `SELECT * INTO #TBCOPY FROM (SELECT *FROM DBO.TBLDATACOPY)` por que la tabla `#TBCOPY` se destruye al terminar el `sp_executesql`.

Comment: ¿De qué motor de base de datos hablar?  Para MySQL puedes hacer esto `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (SELECT * FROM table1)` Para SQL server si es algo diferente

Comment: Para SQL server

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objetivo de crear una tabla temporal sin definir sus columnas? Si sabemos el objetivo es posible que le podamos dar un enfoque diferente a la solución

Comment: El objetivo es crear una tabla temporal para almacenar los datos que devuelve un SELECT * FROM que se ejecuta mediante un EXECUTE sp_executesql. No puedo realizar lo siguiente SELECT * INTO #TBCOPY FROM (SELECT *FROM DBO.TBLDATACOPY) por que la tabla #TBCOPY se destruye al terminar el sp_executesql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ejecuta este ejemplo y me cuentas si se acerca a lo que necesitas, obviamente hacerlo dinámico no seria una opción.

```
USE tempdb
GO

-- Setup test data
IF OBJECT_ID('dept') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dept
CREATE TABLE dept ( deptId INT, deptName VARCHAR(30) )
GO
INSERT INTO dept VALUES ( 1, 'dept 1' ), ( 2, 'dept 2' )
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp
CREATE TABLE #tmp ( deptId INT, deptName VARCHAR(30) )

INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC sp_executesql N'select * from dept'

SELECT * FROM #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: El objetivo es crear una tabla temporal para almacenar los datos que devuelve un SELECT * FROM que se ejecuta mediante un EXECUTE sp_executesql. No puedo realizar lo siguiente SELECT * INTO #TBCOPY FROM (SELECT *FROM DBO.TBLDATACOPY) por que la tabla #TBCOPY se destruye al terminar el sp_executesql

Comment: @DEVJ, Actualice la respuesta con otro ejemplo, mira si acerca a lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 2):

Sí no tienes más que utilizar un SELECT INTO:

```
 SELECT campo1, campo2 INTO #TablaTemporal FROM Tabla;
```

Comment: El objetivo es crear una tabla temporal para almacenar los datos que devuelve un SELECT * FROM que se ejecuta mediante un EXECUTE sp_executesql. No puedo realizar lo siguiente SELECT * INTO #TBCOPY FROM (SELECT *FROM DBO.TBLDATACOPY) por que la tabla #TBCOPY se destruye al terminar el sp_executesql

Comment: Entiendo que crear una tabla temporal global no es una opción

Comment: Exacto... no se debe usar tablas temporales globales

Answer (score 2):

Hay una forma bastante rebuscada de hacerlo para mi gusto, paso a explicarte.

Normalmente cuando queremos crear una tabla temporal dinámicamente sin tener que definir el `CREATE` en primer lugar, lo que hacemos es:

```
SELECT *
       INTO #TMP
       FROM tabla_fisica
```

Esto mismo con el resultado de un SP no es posible hacerlo, si podemos hacer un `INSERT INTO`, pero claramente para esto, debemos conocer la estructura y haber creado la tabla en primer lugar. Una alternativa, es hacer pasar la ejecución del SP por un `OPENROWSET` que de alguna manera simula un Tabla con los resultados, pero para hacer esto, nuestro SQL Server debe tener una configuración especial, por lo que lo primero es reconfigurarlo así:

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Si tenemos posibilidad de mantener esta configuración, entonces podremos hacer:

```
SELECT * INTO #TMP FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', '(Server=local)\SQL2012;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'EXEC Base.Owner.MiSp')
```

Obviamente modificar el dsn de conexión según corresponda, en este ejemplo estamos usando la seguridad integrada, pero se puede configurar usuario/contraseña. Esto tiene sus inconvenientes, dsn en texto claro, un overhead por el uso del OPENROWSET, etc. Si uno puede vivir con esos inconvenientes, esta puede ser una alternativa válida.

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando algun SP (Stored Procedure)? De ser asi, usa tu SELECT INTO convencionalmente, sin el # (Numeral) inicial y va a crear la tabla, trabaja con ella todo lo que necesites, eso si, eliminala antes de que termine el mismo el SP. De no ser asi, determina un mecanismo para eliminarla durante tu proceso para que no te quedes con la tabla de manera indefinida.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
   Select Column1, Column2, Column3
          Into #TuTablaTemporal
   From DBO.TBLDATACOPY
```

De esta manera puedes definir las columnas que quieres tener en tu tabla temporal, es decir si quieres que contenga todas las columnas de la tabla física o solo algunas en especifico, ademas puedes realizar un filtrado de los datos ya que puedes agregar WHERE ademas de hacer Join con otras tablas

Answer (score 0):

Un CTE, le puede servir

```
USE Name_BD
Go
WITH nombreCTE  ( idProducto , Descripcion )

AS
(SELECT ProductDescriptionID, Description FROM Production.ProductDescription)

SELECT * FROM nombreCTE;
```

---

Comment: se te agradece el apoyo pero responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: deberás darle en editar y añadir una explicación de como este script soluciona el problema

Comment: que es un cte? O.o

Comment: No veo como un CTE lo puede ayudar en este caso. Creo que debes elaborar mejor tu respuesta.